# Is it possible to "print" gnuplot's output directly to STDOUT?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am using a third-parter utility named *[gnuplot-iostream](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/)* to invoke gnuplot from C++ in the back-end of a web application. That web application is executed under CGI, so anything that goes to `STDOUT` is the result to browser. In this case, the web request will be for the image itself, so the output will be preceded by some HTTP headers including a `Content-Type` of `image/png`.

Instead of [having gnuplot write to a temporary file, then read that file back into memory and stream its contents to `STDOUT`](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch06_04.html), I'd like to be able to directly pipe GNUPlot's output through `STDOUT`, but I cannot see a way to ask gnuplot to do anything other than write to an image file on disk, or to open an X11 window.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could in principle invoke gnuplot in a pipe and repeatedly poll the output. However, I'd just save it to a file as you're doing now. If it's a problem reading the file in its entirety into memory I'd look for a way to do that piece by piece, maybe?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I just wanted to avoid the roundtrip of storage onto the hard disk and back. Reading the file isn't so much of an issue (indeed, I have to read the bytes from _somewhere_!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a gnuplot script, just don't set an output file to have the image content directed to stdout:

```
gnuplot -e 'set terminal pngcairo; plot x' > myfile.png
```

I'm not completely sure, how that must be integrated with gnuplot-iostream.

Comment: Oh, huh, that's probably what I want. I'll test.

Comment: I guess the key here is that I _can_ pipe out the result if I like (I thought I couldn't), **but** I can't simulatneously pipe in the script so it has to be given on the commandline. BTW I'll probably drop the library wrapper at this point.

Comment: You can also pipe in the script with `gnuplot < myscript.gp > myfile.png` or `echo 'set terminal pngcairo; plot x' | gnuplot > myfile.png`. I think, the wrapper makes sense, if you have some data which you generate in c++ and want to plot this directly.

Comment: The data actually come from a big file on disk (irony) though the script will be generated dynamically. I'm happy rawly piping the result from `popen`; I just wish POSIX had a pleasant way to pipe the config in, too. I really want to avoid all _temporary_ files.

Answer (score 1):

Write to a named pipe? The kind you make with `mkfifo`?

I have used the following silly trick that combines `mkfifo` and `mktemp`:

```
FOO=$(mktemp -d)
mkfifo "$FOO/bar"
# pipe some stuff through "$FOO/bar"
rm -r "$FOO"
```

And remember that nothing stops you from piping through the same named pipe, once you have it.

Comment: Oooh that's a good idea.. I'd run into a few awkwardnesses trying to get a unique filename for the temporary pipe, alas

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know if this is in any way clever, but I have used `mktemp -d` together with `mkfifo` to circumvent that problem.

Comment: `bash` and `ksh` both have the `$RANDOM` variable. something like `fifoname=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM.proj_name` should be *pretty* unique ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: This is a CGI application, not a Bash script.

Comment: if you're creating a fifo, aren't you in a shell? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkfifo.html Ultimately there's a shell behind it, but I wouldn't want to start messing around with Apache's owning shell.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (great name!) ... Ah that explains the impedance mismatch. Can you read from the underlying file system `/dev/random` ? (I don't give up ;-) ). OR use current date/time/(ms if you're lucky) ? And of course, it looks like Christoph has the right idea. Good luck!